# How can I solve this Power BI week date calculation?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I solve this error?

> Function 'SWITCH' does not support comparing values of type True/False with values of type Date. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.

```
Related time period = 
VAR PW = 'Date'[Date]+-1*if(WEEKDAY('Date'[Date])<7,WEEKDAY('Date'[Date]),WEEKDAY('Date'[Date])-7)
VAR pwname=FORMAT('Date'[Date]+-1*if(WEEKDAY('Date'[Date])<7,WEEKDAY('Date'[Date]),WEEKDAY('Date'[Date])-7), "mm/dd")

VAR TotalBlackExternalHire=[Start date_(Sat-Fri)] & " to "& [End date(Sat-Fri)]
VAR totalvlackexterhorename=FORMAT([Start date_(Sat-Fri)] & " to "& [End date(Sat-Fri)], "mm/dd")

VAR INTERNALbLACK=[Start date_(Sat-Fri)] & " to "& [End date(Sat-Fri)]
VAR INTERNALBLACKNAME=FORMAT([Start date_(Sat-Fri)] & " to "& [End date(Sat-Fri)], "mm/dd")

VAR EXTERNALTRANSIN=[Start date_(Sat-Fri)] & " to "& [End date(Sat-Fri)]
VAR EXTERNALTRANSINNAME=FORMAT([Start date_(Sat-Fri)] & " to "& [End date(Sat-Fri)], "mm/dd")

VAR RESULT=
SWITCH(TRUE(),
PW, "C12+ Black Women Representation" & "(" & pwname & ")",
TotalBlackExternalHire, "Total Black External Hire" & "(" & totalvlackexterhorename & ")",
INTERNALbLACK, "Internal Black" & "(" & INTERNALBLACKNAME & ")", 
EXTERNALTRANSIN,"External Transfer IN" & "(" & EXTERNALTRANSINNAME & ")"

RETURN RESULT
```

Comment: Your switch statement doesn't appear to follow the correct syntax.  Please review the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax

Because your first parameter is the boolean statement "true", then PW, TotalBlackExternalHire,INTERNALbLACK, EXTERNAL TRANSIN, all must be type boolean as well